# boost build: How to mark an include as a "system" include

Tags: c++, boost-build, bjam

In `gcc` and `clang`, include directories may be passed to the compiler using `-I` or `-isystem`.

The difference is, `isystem` paths are only searched when angle brackets `<>` are used in an `#include` directive, rather than quotes `""`. Also, certain warnings are suppressed when they appear in system headers (since you presumably can't work around problems in the system headers). (There may be other minor differences as far as I know.)

Not all compilers support this concept, it's an implementation issue, not part of the standard.

[`cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) supports this feature specifically, and will "do the right thing" on compilers that support it.

`scons` historically didn't support it, but there are ways to work around this, and also it has [some support](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/pull-requests/184/support-isystem-in-parseflags/diff) built-in since fairly recently.

Is there an equivalent feature in `boost.build` aka `bjam`, `b2`? In documentation and examples, the include directories are specified using `<include>path/to/files` and passed as a requirement of `lib` or `exe` targets. But I didn't find any `<system_include>` or similar feature.

If it doesn't exist, is there any way to work around it? Some projects won't build without warnings on `gcc` and `clang` unless these flags are used correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in boost.build. What you can do instead is conditionally enable `-isystem` for particular toolsets which do support system includes, for example:

```
exe myexe : mysrc.cpp : <toolset>gcc:<cxxflags>-isystem/path/to/include/files ;
```